# Difference between this to method

Tags: java

I have to use a method to call a joiner with " " as parameter for concatenate string a and b, I have to check if either of the sides are empy (""). 
Both codes works, but i don't get why my reviewer want me to do it in his way. If someone could explain me the benefits of it it would be great.

My method.

```
public static String join(String a, String b) {
    StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
    if (a.endsWith("dieci") || a.endsWith("veinti")) {
        return a + b;
    }       
    if (a.equals("")) {
        return b;
    }
    if (b.contentEquals("")) {
        return a;
    }
    sj.add(a);
    sj.add(b);
    return sj.toString();
}
```

His method.

```
public static String join(String a, String b) {
    if (a.endsWith("dieci") || a.endsWith("veinti")) {
        return a + b;
    }
    return Stream.of(a, b).filter(s ->!s.isEmpty()).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));       
}
```

Comment: Maybe because it is shorter, and easier to understand (once you understand how streams work)?

Comment: @meriton shorter code does not always mean better code. one might use `(a + " " + b).trim()` to basically do the same as the stream, which is also shorter than the stream solution, though it generates an additional String manipulation in this process and thus is less runtime efficient, even though Java will take care through garbage-collection

Comment: Runtime efficiency is a while different topic. Creating streams, filters collectors and underlying buffers might be much heavier. However today approach reduced the code duplication. Probably the initial code is even faster. If I was coming the code review I would refactor the steam statements to a separate method, say joinNonBlank with a variadic parameter. And also check for empty spaces. However, here you compose some numbers with special rules and that might require another named method to test for a merge case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

His is much simpler; in one line it essentially says:

> Take Strings a and b, get rid of the empty ones, and join the remaining ones with spaces, returning the result.

This makes it very clear to see the intention of the code. It also prevents errors, as it would be much easier to have a typo or logic error in your spread-out code that breaks down the implementation into multiple different cases.

Admittedly, this may be harder to understand than your code to start with, as beginners likely won't understand streams. But once you understand them, it is certainly easier to read (at least in this scenario, but not always), and it makes writing such methods much easier. So, it is better to learn such Java constructs now and use them, rather than later.

His code is also much more flexible. If you had to make the method join three Strings, the only modification to his method would be to change `Stream.of(a, b)` to `Stream.of(a, b, c)`. Your method would require much more changes.

Also, using `isEmpty()` is clearer than `.equals("")` as it says what you're doing in more natural English terms. And this again prevents typos, as you could accidentally do `.equals(" ")` (with a space) or something.

Also, why do you use two different methods (`equals` and `contentEquals`) to do the same thing? That is confusing. His method doesn't do that.

Comment: that was just a mistake, it autocomplete and i was tired. Thanks for the replay.

Comment: @nanoroccia gotcha, that's kinda the point of what I'm saying though. The longer code makes it more likely for simple mistakes like that to happen. (But like Roman said, shorter code is not always better, as it can often be less readable. However, in this case, the shorter code increases readability in my opinion.)

Comment: @mapeters my comment was less about readability in general as it was about efficiency. Usually there is a trade-off one has to decide for. Do you care more about memory efficiency, which may require more CPU time, or is memory not a limiting factor and you can focus solely on execution performance? In general different algorithm need to be profiled to see the differences both in runtime and memory behavior. Whether the `trim()` solution in this sample can outperform the stream-solution, which also creates additional objects on the heap, needs to be measured to give qualitative feedback

Comment: @RomanVottner that makes sense. I would say that typically with simple scenarios like this, memory and performance are not very critical (as they are likely negligible compared to the memory/performance of other areas of the code), so readability is more important. Definitely depends on the use case though.

Comment: @mapeters if you design applications for embedded systems or especially mobile devices such considerations should be part of your mindset, if not also of the general workflow. More CPU intense algorithm drain your power-supply/battery more while memory on such devices is usually quite limited, even though modern mobile devices have way more memory available than PCs had around the Millennium

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is always an element of opinion in this kind of thing.  And probably communication and personalities too.  Is it really worth your effort arguing?  If your reviewer wants to rewrite your code in reviews, what's the harm<sup>1</sup>?

Now to the substance.

On the face of it, your reviewer's code is clearly both more concise and easier to understand once you are familiar with Java 8 streams.  And I imagine that the assumption is that everybody working on this project should be familiar with, if not fluent in streams<sup>2</sup>.  It clearly deals with the edge cases more neatly.

I would also argue that your use of a `StringJoiner` to concatenate 2 strings with a space between is overkill.  A simple concatenation expression is both more efficient and easier to understand than what you are doing.

```
   return a + " " + b;
```

The only other point of difference is performance:

- It is not clear to me which one will perform better.  You would need to benchmark the two versions to be sure.
- If you are optimizing for CPU cycles used or garbage generated, neither versions is optimal.

(But note that you should only optimize for performance if you have *concrete evidence* that the performance of this method is critical to the overall application.  If it isn't then optimization is most likely a waste of your time, and a few minutes / hours of your time is probably more costly that a few CPU cycles wasted in millions.)

---

Just for info, if I **needed to** optimize for performance I would write the method like this:

```
public static String join(String a, String b) {
    if (a.isEmpty()) {
        return b;
    } else if (b.isEmpty()) {
        return a;
    } else if (a.endsWith("dieci") || a.endsWith("veinti")) {
        return a + b;
    } else {
        return a + " " + b;
    }
}
```

I will leave the reader to figure out what I have done, and why.  And what (possibly unwarranted) assumptions I have made.

---

<sup>1 - The harm is *if* he is screwing up your or his productivity ...</sup>

<sup>2 - Java 8 is 4+ years old now.  Plenty of time for a professional to learn to use its new features.  And if you are fresh out of Uni and the didn't teach you Java 8 streams ... learn them ASAP!</sup>

Comment: thats the case i only learn basic java on uni. I also think is overkill to use a joiner but he insist on it, so on one hand he demand clean code despice it also demand doing things like a joiner to just concatenate a white space. thanks for reply

Comment: It is also possible that you misunderstood him.  He might have been suggesting `StringJoiner` in a *different context*; e.g. when you have an existing list of strings to join.  But the fact remains that you need to learn Java 8 streams now.   You probably also need to try harder to learn from your reviewer ... which means understanding what he is saying to you.  'Cos from what I can see, he is basically telling you the right thing.  (Hint: don't think you know more than him about Java coding, because the evidence is that you don't ... yet.  He is your teacher at this point.)